# Change Div Font Size & Font

Tags: css, html, fonts

I want to change the font to Segoe UI & font size to full-screen width if possible on a div tag. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want the size to change to screen width so if someone was looking at it from a phone it would be readable to people who need large font sizes normally.

Comment: Use **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** for this. No need to use JS..

Comment: “Font size to full-screen width” does not make sense. There is no attempt at setting font size at all (or anything beyond some odd play with times) in the code posted; Setting font to a specific font family is trivial (though the code shows no attempt at that), but will of course only work if the user’s computer lacks that font.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are meant for exactly what you're asking. Here's an example of how they work:

**HTML**

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

**CSS**

```
DIV {
    font-size:14pt;
}

@media (max-width:450px) {
    /* Increases font size on smaller screen */
    DIV {
        font-size:24pt;
    }
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/uGfAY/ - try resizing the browser window to simulate different screen sizes.

Comment: Can you show an example with the code that I provided. I haven't fully understood

Comment: You can't change the font to screen width using plain CSS, but you can use multiple media queries to change the font size at different resolutions. Perhaps adding at 240px, 320px, 480px, 640px, 720px, etc... and then changing the font size proportionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.className{
font-size:15px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.className{
font-size:20px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
.className{
font-size:25px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.className{
font-size:30px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.className{
font-size:13px;
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
.className{
font-size:12px;
}

}
```

Please use Media Queries